# Issues retrieving users' Facebook photo with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

I'm way behind with my sleep for the last few days and a client of mine has an end-of-the-world problem after moving a website to a new hosting, which I can't figure out. The issue is quite trivial - retrieving the Facebook photo of users. This worked just fine until now, but apparently some setting on the new server are causing it to fail. The problem is that

`file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN&type=large')`

returns an empty string. I also tried using another url, which doesn't rely on an access token (although, the access token is valid, because I get other info about the user):

`file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->id.'/picture?type=large')`

where `$user->id` is the Facebook ID of the user. Manually opening the above URLs in the browser shows the photo, using the same code on my local server also shows them, but on the website the result is always an empty string, no errors, no exceptions.

I checked server settings, openssl is enabled, allow_url_fopen also. Any ideas as to what else can be causing this?

Comment: What error are you actually getting? Presumably an error is coming back from the API, or from your connection stack?

Comment: Also, is the access token for a user (as opposed to a business account and/or page)

Comment: The access token is a for a user account. The permissions are just the basics, plus e-mail. I get all the information about the user - id, name, first_name, last_name, link, etc., no errors.

Comment: Also, adding the same URL (actually, both) shown in the code above inside the src attribute of an HTML img tag shows the photo. It would've been totally weird if it didn't, but anyway.. The issue is only when trying to retrieve the file with file_get_contents(). I can probably work around that and use an alternative way to get to it, but will still be highly interested in why the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Well /<user>/picture returns a HTTP 301 redirect to the image - maybe there's an issue there - have you tried calling /<user>?fields=picture and parsing the URL from that response, rather than trying to directly include it?

Comment: Yep, that did it! I use this URL, parse the returned JSON, get the "picture" out of it and use that with file_get_contents and I am able to retrieve it just like before. Thanks a lot, please move your comment as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be having trouble because `/<user>/picture` returns a HTTP 301 redirect to the image (i.e you can include it directly in an `<img src=""/>`)

Try querying `/<user>?fields=picture` and parsing the URL from that response, rather than trying to directly include it